# PHP : Connect between bot telegram and twitter

Tags: php, twitter, telegram-bot

I need to connect my bot in telegram with my account in twitter, So, We need when i post new tweet in twitter, Post new i telegram.

How can do that.

Comment: i need when i tweet in twitter, automatic post in telegram

Comment: Yes, I got what you need, but we can't simply make it for you. You need to demonstrate some kind of effort and, if you have problems, we will try to help you, but we can't do all the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use a cron for your bot. Have it poll your twitter RSS feed/API every minute or so and if it finds a new tweet...it can forward it to your chat. You will probably have to use something like Memcache or Redis to store the `chat_id` and `last_tweet_id` in cache.

Comment: are you have example ??

Comment: I don't have an example of this specific scenario now. It not just a few lines of code, have you attempted writing any of it? Perhaps there is something specific I can assist with instead of basically creating the entire script.

Comment: i knew what you say first time but the problem in code :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just add your bot token to @manybot in telegram. Then your bot will have options to auto-post from RSS and twitter. No coding needed.